# Proving $P((A$ \ $B) + (B$ \ $C) + (C$ \ $A)) = 1 - P(ABC) - P($ $\overline A\overline B \overline C)$

Tags: probability

> How to prove the following?
> $$P((A \setminus B) + (B \setminus C) + (C \setminus A)) = 1 - P(ABC) - P(\overline A\overline B \overline C)$$

I tried to prove, but I can`t.

[image]

I think decomposing a formula only makes it worse. Please, give me a hint.

Comment: I cannot even understand the notation. What are you talking about?

Comment: P - probability. A\B - difference of event A and event B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think in your notation, $\mathbb P(AB)$ means $\mathbb P(A \cap B)$, right?

**HINT:** If you draw the Venn Diagram, you'll see *why* this is true:  [image: Venn Diagram]

Can you derive a formal proof from this?